# Color Specific Words Using Expression in Power BI Report Builder

Tags: powerbi, dax

So as I in mentioned in the title I am trying to Color Specific Words Using Expression in Power BI Report Builder

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmwMi.png)

As u see in the image the highlighted blue words I am trying to color it so I used this Expression

```
=IIf(Fields!Security_Name.Value = "Equities","#230871","#758493")
```

the problem is that I don't know how to add other words that needs coloring in this expression so any help ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

use "search" formula to create another column, then color rule set use the new column.

New Column = if(search("Equities",[Security_Name],1,0)>0,1,0)

color rule set: 1 = bule, 0 = other.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it can u write the exact code or share a screenshot showing how it's written in RB because I am new to it, so if for example I want to color Equities and Local Equities how would it be done ?!!

Comment: new column is the code no other codes. need several steps in order screenshots may not clear. or send me your file i will make inside of it. my email address: zhangjx7@126.com

Comment: I can't send it as it is sensitive information, the code u entered when I tried it it didn't work so if u could write it in the right format I would be thankful

Comment: there is only one code, but need other steps. demo file removed data is also fine. without file i cannot show you.